# Calculate Running Difference in Dates as New Dataframe Column

Tags: r

I've searched for several days and am still stumped.

Given a dataset defined by the following:

```
ids = c("a","b","c")
dates = c(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01"), as.Date("2015-02-15"))
test = data.frame(ids, dates)
```

I am trying to dynamically add new columns to the data frame whose values will be the difference between the column date (2015-03-01) and the value in the date column. I would expect the result would look like the following, but with a better column name:

```
d20150301 = c(59, 28, 14)
result = data.frame(ids, dates, d20150301)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a vector of dates from a single date, so

```
test$d2015_03_01 <- as.Date('2015-03-01')-test$dates
```

makes `test` look like

```
> test
  ids      dates d2015_03_01
1   a 2015-01-01     59 days
2   b 2015-02-01     28 days
3   c 2015-02-15     14 days
```